# Modify the "exec cwd" path of the process -PM2

Tags: javascript, config, pm2

I have multiple processes that run on the server.

- Each of the processes is placed in it's own directory.
- All of them are controlled by PM2
- Each process is **supposed** to have config and ecosystem files within their folders
- Root folder is supposed to be empty and not related to any processes.

One process that was set up incorrectly. I had to make it work (without touching things that do) so for this process :

- *Pm2 show (id)* indicated that the *exec cwd* is running from root so:
- Copy essential folders and files of the root folder
- Config folder, logs, other essentials had to be copied

I would like to redirect the process from root to its own folder.
It seems I can do it simply by modifying the *exec cwd* but I don't know how to do it.

Please help :)
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Ok well.

It seems it is impossible to modify it like this as this functionality is not implemented.

Therefore:

- copy ecosystem and what you need from folder you are in to where you want it to run from
- delete the process completely
- do cd {path to your desired directory}
- pm2 start ecosystem.config.js

//Additional if you want to keep the process old Id

- pm2 kill (deletes all processes)
- pm2 resurrect (restores them all with original id's)